# How can a thread acquire lock on two objects simultaneously as in this case?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-synchronization

```
public void method(Type1 inst1, Type2 inst2) {
  synchronized(inst1) {
    synchronized(inst2) {
      //do something now
    }
  }
}
```

I can understand from this piece of code that once a thread enters the method, it acquires the lock on inst1, and then it acquires lock on inst2, without releasing inst1 lock. I assume that both of these objects are not locked by other thread.

1. If a thread can acquire lock on only one object at once and can only
   own another lock when lock on current object has been released, how
   can this piece of code be valid, or rather, is it a valid code that I think I have seen somewhere?
2. And what if Type1 and Type2 are same?
3. What happens if we make the method synchronized, considering it resides in
   a class other than the parameter types of the method?

Comment: In theory, there's no limit on the number of locks a thread can hold.  Locks obtained using `synchronized` are implicitly reentrant, so there's no problem with `inst1` and `inst2` referencing the same object.  I assume this is some sort of homework (you should tag it as such if it is).  What it's trying to get you to think about is dead-locks - what would happen if thread 1 calls this method passing `objA` and `objB`, then at the same time thread 2 calls it passing `objB` and `objA`

Comment: This is a code which is commonly used to explain deadlocks. Agree. But I have read in some texts as far as I can remember that a thread can lock only one object at a time, and can not acquire locks on different objects without releasing. That is my doubt!

Comment: There would be no such thing as a deadlock if each thread was only allowed to hold one lock at a time.  You either misunderstood what you read, or what you read was wrong.  Just because somebody wrote it in a blog or a paper or even a book does not make an assertion true.

Comment: If a thread can lock on many different objects one by one without releasing any, then I think definitely it can lock on same object many times. Then why is there a concept of reentrant locking which is explained like some big subtopic? I am talking about only one thread here, and I understand that in case of multiple threads, a deadlock scenario might come up if a thread tries to obtain a lock on an object which is already occupied by another thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1 . If a thread can acquire lock on only one object at once and can only own another lock when lock on current object has been released, how can this piece of code be valid, or rather, is it a valid code that I think I have seen somewhere?

It is a valid code, the locks are not on the object where the method resides, but on `inst1` and `inst2`. Also, the lock is not on the class, but for every object

> 2 . And what if Type1 and Type2 are same?

again, the locks are on the objects, not on the classes. if inst1 and inst2 are the same, then the thread has only one lock, it is valid for the same thread to "re-enter" the lock

> 3 . What happens if we make the method synchronized, considering it resides in a class other than the parameter types of the method?

Then you have yet another lock, this time on the object (not the class) where the method is being executed.

Comment: can a single thread lock on multiple objects at the same time?

Comment: @xploreraj Evident from nested synchronized blocks that it has lock on both inst1 and inst2.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to *@morgano* and *@Nick Holt*, I understand that **a thread can hold multiple locks at the same time** (different objects), or on the same object multiple times (locks obtained using `synchronized` are implicitly reentrant).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code in case every time you need to obtain lock on those two objects you do it in the same order.

For example, if you have two methods

```
public void methodA(Type1 inst1, Type2 inst2) {
  synchronized(inst1) {
    synchronized(inst2) {
      //do something now
    }
  }
}

public void methodB(Type1 inst1, Type2 inst2) {
  //wrong
  synchronized(inst2) {
    synchronized(inst1) {
      //do something now
    }
  }
}
```

You have a potential deadlock problem as a thread could obtain the lock on inst1 and wait for the lock of inst2, while another thread have the lock on inst2 and wait for lock on inst1.

Comment: ok, but this is not my doubt! i have doubt on how thread is locking two objects simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

That  code  is very likely to  result in  a deadlock minefield, for sure.

The 2nd  thread(threa2) that locks inst2 does not  necessarily have to be running through  methodA, but may lock object  inst2 in another procedure, and does so before the thread1 in methodA, and then accesses method A and attempts to lock inst2, before releasing  inst2.  ahhhhh! boooom! :(.

suggested solution :
synchronize on methodA, and  not  on the objects  , as that will  lock all resources   accessed in methodA() 
like so

public synchronized void methodA () {....}

Answer (score 0):

Deadlocks happen when you acquire one lock inside another:

```
lock OB1 {
   lock OB2 { ... }
}
```

because one could attempt to lock on a pair `(1,2)` and anther `(2,1)`. There are possible more lengthy chains: `(1,2)` + `(2,3)` + `(3,1)`.

You need to introduce **order** between locks to avoid deadlocks: [Java synchronisation: atomically moving money across account pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280857/java-synchronisation-atomically-moving-money-across-account-pairs)