# Java synchronisation: atomically moving money across account pairs?

Tags: java, multithreading

How can I make money transfer from one account to another **atomic**? For class:

```
public class Account {
    public Account(BigDecimal initialAmount) {...}
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {...}
    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {...}
}
```

I expect following pseudo-code:

```
public boolean transfer(Account from, Account to, BigDecimal amount) {
    BigDecimal fromValue = from.getAmount();
    if (amount.compareTo(fromValue) < 0)
         return false;
    BigDecimal toValue = to.getAmount();
    from.setAmount(fromValue.add(amount.negate()));
    to.setAmount(toValue.add(amount));
    return true;
}
```

updates accounts safely in a single threaded (or sequential) environment.

In case of multithreaded / concurrent environment I see danger cases:

```
acc1 --> acc2  ||  acc2 --> acc1
acc1 --> acc2  ||  acc2 --> acc3  ||  acc3 --> acc1
...
```

Easiest solution is to block on shared object, but it will be inefficient for cases like:

```
acc1 --> acc2  ||  acc3 --> acc4  and  acc1 != acc3 and acc2 != acc4
```

**I expect independent transfers are performed in parallel.**

**UPDATE** Seems that suggested solution:

```
synchronize (acc1) {
   synchronize (acc2) {
     ....
   }
}
```

lead to deadlock as 2 locks acquired sequentially...

**UPDATE 2** *what do you mean with "update accounts safely in multithreading environment" exactly? Is the only worry that the accounts won't end up having minus funds or is there some other problem?*

If `acc1(2); acc2(3)` and `acc1 --1--> acc2` and `acc2 --2--> acc1` I expect consistency: `(acc1, acc2)` has `(3, 2)` value, but not `(4, 2)` or `(3, 4)`. Total should be 5, and not 1+3=4 or 4+3=7.

*how much concurrent transaction are you expecting at a time ?* 1000-10000 - so lock on shared object isn't efficient.

Comment: Lock both of the accounts. But beware of deadlocks.

Comment: How to avoid deadlock? I don't know a way to block atomically on 2 object simultaneously.

Comment: One way of doing it is by acquiring each lock in the same order across each threads. If you're accounts have unique IDs, then that's not too hard.

Comment: why not make transfer method static synchronized?

Comment: *why not make transfer method static synchronized?* I wrote about this in question - for performance reason - why hold lock for independent transfers?

Comment: what do you mean with "update accounts safely in multithreading environment" exactly? Is the only worry that the accounts won't end up having minus funds or is there some other problem?

Comment: how much concurrent transaction are you expecting at a time ?

Comment: Give each account a [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) object. Order the accounts by name/id. `lock` each `Lock` object and transfer the money. `unlock` in a `finally`. Done.

Comment: the number of 1000-10000 is still to vague. On how many accounts are those transactions going on?

Comment: What if both accounts make a transfer to each other at the same time? So, why not make the transaction an entity by itself like `Transfer`, and handle them separately, with a mechanism that tie it to the accounts

Comment: *So, why not make the transaction an entity by itself like Transfer?* Brining transactions make implementation harder. I stay with restrictions to make independent transfers in parallel, dependent in sequence. That make total amount constant and money balance consistent after finishing all operations.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

A simple solution could be to use a lock per account, but to avoid deadlock you have to acquire locks in the same order always. So, you could have a final account ID, and acquire the lock of the account with a less id first:

```
public void transfer(Account acc1, Account acc2, BigDecimal value) {
    Object lock1 = acc1.ID < acc2.ID ? acc1.LOCK : acc2.LOCK;
    Object lock2 = acc1.ID < acc2.ID ? acc2.LOCK : acc1.LOCK;
    synchronized (lock1) {
       synchronized (lock2) {
          acc1.widrawal(value);
          acc2.send(value);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Having lock object inside an account (or, the same, locking on account object itself) means one need to ensure that only one instance of particular account exists inside JVM.

Comment: Instead of using a `LOCK` field, you can just use the account object itself as the lock.

Comment: @tcooc - That would still require having only one copy of an account object.

Comment: As a more general solution, you can use as many and as granular locks as you like and never worry about deadlock or livelock as long as you always acquire any and all locks in the same order.

Comment: I wonder if the deadlock could be avoided if Account object's debit and credit methods are synchronized? then would be run into race conditions?

Answer (score 15):

One way to do this is to have a transaction log. Before moving the money, you'll need to write to the transaction log of each account what you intend to do. The log should contain: the amount of money that's taken in/out of the account, and an lock which is shared between the log pair.

Initially the lock should be in a blocked state. You created the log pair, one with amount of X and the other with amount of -X, and both shares a lock. Then deliver the log entry to the inbox of the respective accounts, the account from which money is taken out should reserve that amount. Once you've confirmed that they're delivered safely, then release the lock. The moment the lock is released you're at a point if no return. The accounts then should resolve themselves.

If either of the party want to fail the transaction at any time before the lock is released, then simply remove the logs and return the reserved amount to the main balance.

This approach may be a bit heavy, but it would also work in a distributed scenario where the accounts actually are in different machines, and the inboxes actually would have to be persisted, to ensure money never get lost if any of the machine crashes/goes offline unexpectedly. Its general technique is called two phase locking.

Comment: Are there exist any transaction log Java libraries?

Comment: This looks like really really awesome introduction to log-based persistence and it contains quite a few links to implementations: http://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying

Answer (score 8):

I would propose to create a method Account.withdraw(amount) which throws an exception if it doesn't have sufficient funds. This method needs to be synchronized on the account itself.

Edit:

There also needs to be a Account.deposit(amount) method which is synchronized on the receiving account instance.

Basically this will result in a lock of the first account while withdrawing and then another lock on the receiving account while depositing. So two locks but not at the same time.

**Code sample:** Assumes that withdraw/deposit are synchronized and return boolean success status rather than throw exception.

```
public boolean transfer(Account from, Account to, BigDecimal amount) {
    boolean success = false;
    boolean withdrawn = false;
    try {
        if (from.withdraw(amount)) {
            withdrawn = true;
            if (to.deposit(amount)) {
                success = true;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (withdrawn && !success) {
            from.deposit(amount);
        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: what about two object of same account ?

Comment: I was about to suggest something like this, but you **would** need a synchronized `deposit(amount)` on the other account to avoid race conditions. I'm thinking of a case where concurrent deposits call `setAmount()` and would result in overwriting one of the deposits. `setAmount()` is just a no-no for this situation.

Comment: @Kevin, yes, you are right. Will add it to the answer.

Comment: @Christian Looks good. I hope you don't mind that I added a code sample to your answer -- as long as it gets through peer review.

Comment: @Christian i dont know whether what i am thinking is write or not but think on this case  as locking will be on account object so what if  i have created two objects with same account number ?

Comment: What about situation when, say, target account becomes disabled (no withdraws/deposits permitted) right after you withdrawn from source account, but before you did a deposit?

Comment: @Christian The code sample I added returns boolean instead of throwing exception, which simplifies the rollback code over using exception handling. I hope that doesn't roam too far from what you were thinking.

Comment: @Victor to have real atomicity it's getting complex and one needs to have a transaction log to be able to reconstruct all transactions in an error case.

Comment: @VictorSorokin As long as `Account.deposit()` rejects deposits on a canceled account you can know to rollback. Well, there is still the oddity of withdraw -> cancel "from" account -> cancel "to" account -> failed deposit due to cancelled "to" account -> failed rollback deposit due to canceled "from" account. Who gets the money now? This could be more profitable than the Office Space rounding scheme.

Comment: @Christian To have atomicity all what is needed is a method to lock several accounts upon method's completion. Once you locked accounts participating in transfer, you have guarantee transfer won't violate business rules.

Answer (score 7):

You can create an extra `Account` `T` that exists solely for transferring the money. So if you want to transfer from `A` to `B` you actually transfer from `A` to `T` and then from `T` to `B`. For each of these transfers you only lock either `A` or `B` depending on which account is participating in the transfer. Since you are using the same type for transfers, you end up with little extra code and therefore low maintenance costs.

To reduce the number of extra accounts you could hold them in a pool. If you have a thread pool that is processing transfers, than you can assign each thread it's own extra account. Therefore you don't need to request and release those extra accounts from/to a pool too often.

Comment: Same solution as Petr's. Thanks!

Comment: @gavenkoa Not exactly, because Petr does not use an extra account and my solution doesn't require a specific lock ordering between accounts `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to use kind of "striped lock" with lock/unlock methods operating on several locks. Accounts are mapped to locks using `hashCode`, the more locks you allocate, the more parallelism you get.

Here's code sample:

```
public class StripedLock {

    private final NumberedLock[] locks;

    private static class NumberedLock {
        private final int id;
        private final ReentrantLock lock;

        public NumberedLock(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            this.lock = new ReentrantLock();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Default ctor, creates 16 locks
     */
    public StripedLock() {
        this(4);
    }

    /**
     * Creates array of locks, size of array may be any from set {2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64}
     * @param storagePower size of array will be equal to <code>Math.pow(2, storagePower)</code>
     */
    public StripedLock(int storagePower) {
        if (!(storagePower >= 1 && storagePower <= 6)) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("storage power must be in [1..6]"); }

        int lockSize = (int) Math.pow(2, storagePower);
        locks = new NumberedLock[lockSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < locks.length; i++)
            locks[i] = new NumberedLock(i);
    }

    /**
     * Map function between integer and lock from locks array
     * @param id argument
     * @return lock which is result of function
     */
    private NumberedLock getLock(int id) {
        return locks[id & (locks.length - 1)];
    }

    private static final Comparator<? super NumberedLock> CONSISTENT_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<NumberedLock>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(NumberedLock o1, NumberedLock o2) {
            return o1.id - o2.id;
        }
    };


    public void lockIds(@Nonnull int[] ids) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(ids);
        NumberedLock[] neededLocks = getOrderedLocks(ids);
        for (NumberedLock nl : neededLocks)
            nl.lock.lock();
    }

    public void unlockIds(@Nonnull int[] ids) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(ids);
        NumberedLock[] neededLocks = getOrderedLocks(ids);
        for (NumberedLock nl : neededLocks)
            nl.lock.unlock();
    }

    private NumberedLock[] getOrderedLocks(int[] ids) {
        NumberedLock[] neededLocks = new NumberedLock[ids.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            neededLocks[i] = getLock(i);
        }
        Arrays.sort(neededLocks, CONSISTENT_COMPARATOR);
        return neededLocks;
    }
}

    // ...
    public void transfer(StripedLock lock, Account from, Account to) {
        int[] accountIds = new int[]{from.getId(), to.getId()};
        lock.lockIds(accountIds);
        try {
            // profit!
        } finally {
            lock.unlockIds(accountIds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It will lead to one of callers to be blocked until winner finishes with it's transfer, just as I've stated in my answer.

Comment: In several answers I see that solution is to make locks in predefined order to avoid deadlock. Thanks for answer!

Comment: but depending on the ordering of of the elements in `int[] ids` you could still end up with a mixed up order of lock aquisition and are therefore prone to to deadlocking. Another thing to make sure is that the sorting algorithm used by `Arrays.sort` is stable. Not sure if this is guaranteed by the java API.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker `sort` is stable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator). Therefore, ordering of locks is the same across all calls to `lockIds, unlockIds`.

Comment: @VictorSorokin But what if two account ids have the same identity hashcode and two transactions going on from one to each other at the same time.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker your comment made me re-check if `identityHashCode` can return same value for different objects, and it indeed can. I've updated answer to use explicit `ints` for ordering.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use built-in synchronization, use a Lock object. Use tryLock() to get an exclusive lock on both accounts at the same time. If either one fails, then release both locks and wait a random amount of time and try again.

Comment: I personally don't like `sleep()` calls in code and expect that wait/interrupt operation performed by high level data type / algorithm.

Comment: You're missing the point - it's not sleep() for polling reasons, it's sleep() to intentionally add a random factor that backs off from the locks, allowing other threads an opportunity to get the exclusive locks.

Comment: I see your solution in https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK07-J.+Avoid+deadlock+by+requesting+and+releasing+locks+in+the+same+order  it uses `Thread.sleep(1000 + number.nextInt(1000));` to prevent to prevent **livelock**

Comment: That's funny that it's almost the exact same example and solution as we're discussing here. I like the approach of getting the syncs in a consistent order, that's a good approach as well.

Comment: Backing off in this manner is exactly what can lead to poor performance and potential livelock. If two accounts are very popular and there's a transaction that involves them both, there's a high potential it could block indefinitely.

Comment: @Danikov: It depends on the ratio of the time to secure both locks vs the range of wait time. If the time to secure both locks is 1 millisecond and the backoff time is a random number between 10-110 milliseconds, then on average you'll have a 1% chance of delay for each attempt. Now if you had 100 threads all trying to get the lock, then you would run into problems, but if you knew that your usage pattern might involve 100 threads competing, you'd increase your backoff range to 10-1,010 milliseconds.

Comment: However, I do agree that the ordered lock approach is the better one.

Comment: If you are intentionally sleeping, you are blocking a system resource - the sleeping thread - from doing something useful. It would be better to reschedule the transfer for a later time and go on with another one at least.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker by that logic, the entire application should be single-threaded. I would assume that the OP is asking about synchronization because they've already made the decision to have one thread per transaction.

Comment: @JesseBarnum the problem with the random backoff is you're acting without knowledge of why your tryLock failed and hoping the randomness is enough to overcome the underlying issue. Poorly implemented avoidance strategies are exactly what lead to livelock. Randomness can be used to break symmetric problems, but the subsequent asymmetric problem can discard the randomness and act fairly.

Answer (score 5):

As stated previously, you should lock on both accounts, always in the same order. The key part, however, is ensuring both high granularity and singularity across the VM instance. This can be done using [`String.intern()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()):

```
public boolean transfer(Account from, Account to, BigDecimal amount) {
    String fromAccountId = from.id.toString().intern();
    String toAccountId = to.id.toString().intern();
    String lock1, lock2;

    if (from.id < to.id) {
       lock1 = fromAccountId;
       lock2 = toAccountId;
    } else {
       lock1 = toAccountId;
       lock2 = fromAccountId;
    }

    // synchronizing from this point, since balances are checked
    synchronized(lock1) {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            BigDecimal fromValue = from.getAmount();
            if (amount.compareTo(fromValue) < 0)
                 return false;

            BigDecimal toValue = to.getAmount();
            from.setAmount(fromValue.add(amount.negate()));
            to.setAmount(toValue.add(amount));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting technique. I consider to use some prefixes to avoid collision with another parts which uses same technique: `("trasfer" + from.id.toString()).intern()`

Comment: Do the locks still apply correctly because they are no longer a field but derivative of a field of the Account object ?

Answer (score 4):

As you have mentioned there will be 1000-10000 concurrent transaction you expecting at a time than you can store accounts on which some transaction is going on and handle concurrency

One Solution is to allow system to create only one object of particulate account id, means that if you want to make a transaction between account "123" and "456" than your thread will create account object and in that constructor of account class we will check if any other object of account is there with particulate account id, if other object of account is there with same account id means that some transaction is going on with particulate account id so you have to wait to get the account object.

So we can do transaction between "123" and "456" and at same time we can do transaction between "abc" and "xyz" but if at same time some other thread will try to create object of account "123" than system will say please wait

for reference you can see below code

Please note :

1. dont forgote to remove your account id from locks map by call to  freeAccount(BigDecimal accId) from LockHolder class
2. I have used HasMap instand of list because list will not be a good choice when you are randomly removing element from it(or when frequently you are updating it)

   ```
   package test;

   import java.math.BigDecimal;
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Map;

   public class T {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Account ac, ac2;

       try {
           ac = new Account(new BigDecimal("123"));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
           ac2 = new Account(new BigDecimal("123"));
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please Wait");
       }

   }
   }

   class Account {
    public Account(BigDecimal accId) throws Exception {
       if (LockHolder.isLocked(accId)) {
           throw new Exception();
       } else {
           LockHolder.setLock(accId);
       }
    }
   }

   class LockHolder {
    public static  Map<BigDecimal, Integer> locks = new HashMap<BigDecimal, Integer>();

    public synchronized static boolean isLocked(BigDecimal accId) {
       return LockHolder.locks.containsKey(accId);
    }

    public synchronized static void setLock(BigDecimal accId) {
       LockHolder.locks.put(accId , 1);
    }
    public synchronized static void freeAccount(BigDecimal accId) {
       LockHolder.locks.remove(accId);
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: You miss code for managing money transfer - question about how to make transfer consistent in multithreading environment.

Comment: @gavenkoa here what i have done is if there is some transaction is going with any account then i am not allowing to create second instance of that account so there will be no need to worry in transaction because if you have account object it means no other thread is editing that account...

Comment: @gavenkoa i added more details about how to make transfer consistent in multithreading environment

Comment: How about using ConcurrentHashMap ?

Answer (score 2):

An approach which will remain robust even if threads may get arbitrarily waylaid is to have each account maintain a list of transactions requested or posted against it.  To request a transfer from one account to another, create a transaction object defining the request and add it to the request queue for the source account.  If that account can perform the transaction, it should move it to its list of posted transactions and add it to the request queue for the destination.  Using `AtomicReference` it's possible to ensure that from the moment the transaction is placed into the queue for the first account, the state of the system will always thereafter either have the transaction pending, completed, or aborted, and even if some or all threads were to get waylaid, examining the transaction lists would make it possible to determine what money belonged where.

By contrast, when using locks, events which unexpectedly delay one thread can arbitrarily impede the execution of many others, and if a thread gets killed off while holding a lock it may be impossible to determine what exactly it had or had not done prior to that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for interest to question.

I found several solutions in https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/LCK07-J.+Avoid+deadlock+by+requesting+and+releasing+locks+in+the+same+order

As one link answer was removed here essential piece of code that help anyone when cert.org fall. Pieces are long so I didn't include any pros/cons.

**Private Static Final Lock Object**:

```
final class BankAccount {
  private double balanceAmount;  // Total amount in bank account
  private static final Object lock = new Object();

  BankAccount(double balance) {
    this.balanceAmount = balance;
  }

  // Deposits the amount from this object instance
  // to BankAccount instance argument ba
  private void depositAmount(BankAccount ba, double amount) {
    synchronized (lock) {
      if (amount > balanceAmount) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Transfer cannot be completed");
      }
      ba.balanceAmount += amount;
      this.balanceAmount -= amount;
    }
  }

  public static void initiateTransfer(final BankAccount first,
    final BankAccount second, final double amount) {

    Thread transfer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          first.depositAmount(second, amount);
        }
    });
    transfer.start();
  }
}
```

**Ordered Locks**:

```
final class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount> {
  private double balanceAmount;  // Total amount in bank account
  private final Object lock;

  private final long id; // Unique for each BankAccount
  private static long NextID = 0; // Next unused ID

  BankAccount(double balance) {
    this.balanceAmount = balance;
    this.lock = new Object();
    this.id = this.NextID++;
  }

  @Override public int compareTo(BankAccount ba) {
     return (this.id > ba.id) ? 1 : (this.id < ba.id) ? -1 : 0;
  }

  // Deposits the amount from this object instance
  // to BankAccount instance argument ba
  public void depositAmount(BankAccount ba, double amount) {
    BankAccount former, latter;
    if (compareTo(ba) < 0) {
      former = this;
      latter = ba;
    } else {
      former = ba;
      latter = this;
    }
    synchronized (former) {
      synchronized (latter) {
        if (amount > balanceAmount) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException(
              "Transfer cannot be completed");
        }
        ba.balanceAmount += amount;
        this.balanceAmount -= amount;
      }
    }
  }

  public static void initiateTransfer(final BankAccount first,
    final BankAccount second, final double amount) {

    Thread transfer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
          first.depositAmount(second, amount);
        }
    });
    transfer.start();
  }
}
```

**Compliant Solution (ReentrantLock)**:

```
final class BankAccount {
  private double balanceAmount;  // Total amount in bank account
  private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Random number = new Random(123L);

  BankAccount(double balance) {
    this.balanceAmount = balance;
  }

  // Deposits amount from this object instance
  // to BankAccount instance argument ba
  private void depositAmount(BankAccount ba, double amount)
                             throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
      if (this.lock.tryLock()) {
        try {
          if (ba.lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
              if (amount > balanceAmount) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Transfer cannot be completed");
              }
              ba.balanceAmount += amount;
              this.balanceAmount -= amount;
              break;
            } finally {
              ba.lock.unlock();
            }
          }
        } finally {
          this.lock.unlock();
        }
      }
      int n = number.nextInt(1000);
      int TIME = 1000 + n; // 1 second + random delay to prevent livelock
      Thread.sleep(TIME);
    }
  }

  public static void initiateTransfer(final BankAccount first,
    final BankAccount second, final double amount) {

    Thread transfer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            first.depositAmount(second, amount);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // Reset interrupted status
          }
        }
    });
    transfer.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be just reorder locks?

Please criticize if that solution is bad and why?

```
public void transfer(Account acc1, Account acc2, BigDecimal value) {
    synchronized (acc1) {
          acc1.widrawal(value);
    }

    boolean success = false;
    try {
        synchronized (acc2) {
            acc2.send(value);
            success = true;
        }
    } finally {
        synchronized (acc1) {
           if (!success) {
              // revert transaction back if we had any exceptions,
              // Thread interruptions and so one
              acc1.send(value);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not all resources are dividable like amounts. Your solution assumes there is a rollback for `withdraw` operation (you named it as `send`). **Your rollback operation isn't synchronized**, making your code unusable.

Comment: @gavenkoa No problems, I've added synchronization into rollback section of code

Comment: Your solution is the same as of **SpaceTrucker**