# Adding money from one account to another using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 2 accounts and 2 threads. 1 thread transfers money from 1 account to 2 account, 2 thread transfers money from 2 account to 1 account, if of course there is enough money. I need to realize the deadlock situation and solve the deadlock situation confirming safe transfer. Here is what I have for now:

**Account.java**

```
public class Account {

    private /*volatile*/ long balance;

    public Account() {
        this(0L);
    }

    public Account(long balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public long getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(long amount) {
        checkAmountNonNegative(amount);
        balance += amount;
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(long amount) {
        checkAmountNonNegative(amount);
        if (balance < amount) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("not enough money");
        }
        balance -= amount;
    }

    private static void checkAmountNonNegative(long amount) {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("negative amount");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account first = new Account(1_000_000);
        Account second = new Account(1_000_000);

        TransferThread thread1 = new TransferThread(first, second, 2000);
        TransferThread thread2 = new TransferThread(second, first, 2000);

        CompletableFuture.allOf(
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(thread1),
                CompletableFuture.runAsync(thread2)
        ).join();

        System.out.println(first.getBalance());
        System.out.println(second.getBalance());
    }
}
```

**TransferThread.java**

```
public class AccountThread implements Runnable {

    private final Account from;
    private final Account to;
    private final long amount;

    public AccountThread(Account from, Account to, long amount) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            // my realization
            try {
                if (from.getBalance() < 0) {
                    throw new InsufficientFundsException();
                } else {
                    from.deposit(amount);
                    to.withdraw(amount);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I decided to put synchronized to both methods deposit and withdraw for safe transfering. But doubt with the method run realization. Do I have a rigth implementation? If not, explanation and correction will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to put `try-catch` in `synchronized` block with same monitor object. In case of synchronized methods lock is acquired on the object. Here you have two accounts so two separate locks.

Comment: Also money is withdrown first, if successful then deposited to target account.

Comment: @onkarruikar To be honest didnt get you with try-catch, can you show me an example?

Comment: A money transfer is a classical example of a deadlock problem. You don't need to use volatile or synchronize or anything else in your Account class. You should just lock both accounts before transfer and then release them. And to avoid deadlocks you have to introduce some kind of ordering and lock a pair of accounts in their order, as @StephenC described

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java synchronisation: atomically moving money across account pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29280857/java-synchronisation-atomically-moving-money-across-account-pairs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your solution is not vulnerable to deadlocks because the `TransferThread` instances are never going to hold more than one lock at a time.

However, I don't think it is a correct solution.  The problems are here:

```
if (from.getBalance() < 0) {
    throw new InsufficientFundsException();
} else {
    from.deposit(amount);
    to.withdraw(amount);
}
```

The first problem is you are transferring money in the wrong direction!  Money should go from the `from` account to the `to` account.  But you are *depositing* money into the `from` account and *withdrawing* money from the `to` account.

Customers won't be happy about that.

Lets fix that:

```
if (from.getBalance() < 0) {
    throw new InsufficientFundsException();
} else {
    to.deposit(amount);
    from.withdraw(amount);
}
```

The problem now is that we are depositing before we withdraw.  Why is that a problem?  Because between the `from.getBalance()` and `from.withdraw(...)` calls, another thread could make a withdrawl from the `from` account.  That could mean that *our* `from.withdraw(amount)` call could fail.  But we've already deposited the money into the `to` account.  Ooops!

Lets fix *that*:

```
if (from.getBalance() < 0) {
    throw new InsufficientFundsException();
} else {
    from.withdraw(amount);
    // HERE
    to.deposit(amount);
}
```

Close ...

What happens if we get a power dip at the point marked HERE?  Well, if we dealing with real bank accounts, then we would actually be storing the information in a database.  So the values currently in the accounts would be preserved.  But at the point labelled HERE we would have withdrawn money from one account and not deposited it in the other one.  What happens to that money?  Poof!  Gone!

Does that matter?  Well it depends on how we frame the requirements.  Assuming that it is OK to represent the bank accounts as (only) in memory objects, I'd say that we can ignore that nicety of surviving power failure during a transfer.  The power failure would blow away the accounts as well.

Close enough is good enough, here.  But we can do slightly better.  As we noted, the value in the `from` account can change between the `getBalance()` and `withdraw()` calls, so that the `withdraw()` could fail.  But when you think about it `from.withdraw` is just testing `from.getBalance() < 0` anyway.  So, we can just get rid of the test:

```
    from.withdraw(amount);
    to.deposit(amount);
```

If the `from.withdraw(amount)` is going to overdraw the account, it will fail with an exception.  And we won't then do the `to.deposit(amount)` call.

---

Now we could try to implement a `transfer` method that takes two accounts as arguments, and transfers money from one to the other as an atomic operation.  You could conceivably do this by acquiring locks on both accounts before doing the transfer; e.g. like this:

```
  public static void transfer(Account from, Account to, long amount {
      synchronized (from) {
          synchronized (to) {
              from.withdraw(amount);
              to.deposit(amount);
          }
      }
  }
```

<sup>(I'm deliberately ignoring the exceptions and exception handling.)</sup>

But *now* we have to worry about deadlock.  For example, if one thread tries to transfer money from A to B, and another simultaneously transfer money from B to A.

There are ways to deal with this:

- One way is to the `Lock` API and `acquire` the locks with a timeout to detect deadlock.
- Another way is write the transfer method to acquire the account locks in the same order when doing `transfer(A,B)` and `transfer(B,A)`.  For example, assuming that `Account` objects have unique account numbers, then lock the `Account` with the lower account number first.

  ```
    public static void transfer(Account from, Account to, long amount {
        if (from.getAccountNo() < to.getAccountNo()) {
            synchronized (from) {
                synchronized (to) {
                    from.withdraw(amount);
                    to.deposit(amount);
                }
            }
        } else {
            synchronized (to) {
                synchronized (from) {
                    from.withdraw(amount);
                    to.deposit(amount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
  ```

Comment:  taking lower account number as first lock is what I was going suggest.

Comment: But what about getAccountNo() ? Should I add any id there?

Comment: Yea.  If you are going use that technique to avoid deadlocks, then you need to record each account's unique account number, and provide a way to access it.

Comment: @StephenC And can I add random id?

Comment: No.  The ids need to be unique.  Random numbers are not unique.  (If you ever have two accounts with the same id, then you risk a deadlock because the account ordering by id is no longer a total ordering.) The identity hashcode can't be used for the same reason.

Comment: Interesting. I am cheking the changed code and it stucks sometimes anyway)

Answer (score 1):

For more information about synchronized blocks refer. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

When we make methods synchronized, a thread acquires lock on the object on which the method was called. Here there are two account objects so there are two separate locks. One thread will not wait to execute `from.withdraw(amount);` when other thread is executing `to.deposit(amount);`.
If we put the transaction logic in a synchronized block then one thread has to wait till other finishes the entire transaction.

Put business logic in `synchronized` block like this:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Account first = new Account(1_000_000);
        Account second = new Account(1_000_000);

        AccountThread task1 = new AccountThread(first, second, 2000, first, second);
        AccountThread task2 = new AccountThread(second, first, 2000, first, second);
        
        CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture.runAsync(task1), CompletableFuture.runAsync(task2)).join();

        System.out.println(first.getBalance());
        System.out.println(second.getBalance());
    }
}

class AccountThread implements Runnable {
    private static int count = 0;
    private final Account from;
    private final Account to;
    private final long amount;
    private final Object lock1;
    private final Object lock2;

    public AccountThread(Account from, Account to, long amount, Object lock1, Object lock2) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.lock1 = lock1;
        this.lock2 = lock2;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++) {
            synchronized (lock1) {
                synchronized (lock2) {
                    try {
                        if (from.getBalance() < 0) {
                            throw new RuntimeException();
                        } else {
                            from.withdraw(amount);
                            to.deposit(amount);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
not enough money
710000
1290000
```

Up side is this solution locks threads only on concerned objects.
 Please do share better solutions.

Comment: What is the reason one account always have the same amount of money, if we are transfering from both accounts?

Comment: You haven't shared `TransferThread.class` implementation. You've shared `AccountTread.class` implementation. So I don't know what is happening. Sometimes I get final balance as `1000000` for both accounts, that means both threads got equal opportunity to perform transactions.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that all operations on any bank account will be using a single shared lock.  That makes it a concurrency bottleneck.  There are better solutions.

Comment: @StephenC Using two shared lock?

Comment: You can acquire lock on `from` and `to` objects like this to avoid bottleneck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23217190/how-can-a-thread-acquire-lock-on-two-objects-simultaneously-as-in-this-case

Comment: @onkarruikar Is it possible to change the code the way you said above? Just to accept the best answer

Comment: I have updated the code. Trick is to synchronize in same order. This may not be the best solution. But there is no concurrency bottleneck anymore.

Comment: You still have a problem because the locks are not actually associated with the accounts.  Indeed, they are not even shared between different instances of `AccountThread` so there won't actually be any mutual exclusion due to the `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: See my answer.  The semantics (and assumptions) of this problem are such that you don't actually need to hold two locks at the same time.  Thus you can avoid the deadlock problem entirely.

Comment: @StephenC Thanks for the info! If we consider this as in-memory and no-database bank, then I've passed both account objects themselves as locks and they will be acquired in same order in both threads. If the requirement evolves and we add more threads and accounts and database then things change.

Comment: Well yes ... but how do you deal with an indefinite number of bank accounts?

Comment: Like you suggested, pass a transaction-task two locks. With lowest account number object as first lock. For multiple objects we either have to treat accounts as locks or create separate account-lock map. But for infinite accounts this won't remain in-memory bank. :D With database in play this strategy wont work.